# Is the language of all deciders recognizing empty language decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

I TA for a course in theory of computation and this came up as an interesting question.

$E_{TM}$ is the set of TM descriptions where the machine's language is empty.

Of course, $E_{TM}$ is undecidable for arbitrary TMs (as well as $A_{TM}$).

Now suppose we restrict our attention to *decider* TMs (ones that always halt).

$A_{decider}$ is the set of TM *decider* descriptions and strings such that the TM accepts that string, and $E_{decider}$ is the same as $E_{TM}$ except for deciders.

Of course, $A_{decider}$ now is decidable because we just simulate the decider on the input, and it will always stop.

Is $E_{decider}$ decidable now, or does it remain undecidable?
The reduction to show that $E_{TM}$ was undecidable originally goes in the wrong direction here.

Comment: I think that you want to study _separability_ rather than decidability. The point is, you can't write a TM accepting $A_{decider}$ and rejecting its complement, since its complement contains descriptions of non-deciders as well! You want a TM which accepts $A_{decider}$ and reject the set $B$ of pairs (decider,string) where the decider rejects the strings. On pairs (nondecider,string), you do not care about accepting/rejecting, or even terminating. This notion is called separability of $A_{decider}$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

$E_{decider}$ is even unrecognizable.

Suppose a TM $E$ recognizes $E_{decider}$, we construct a TM $N$ recognizing $\overline{H}=\{\langle\langle M\rangle, w\rangle\mid M(w) \text{ doesn't halt}\}$, which is known as unrecognizable, thus a contradiction. $N$ works as follows.

On input $\langle\langle M\rangle, w\rangle$:

1. Construct a TM $M_w$ working on input $x$ as follows

   1. Run $M$ on $w$ with at most $|x|$ steps.
   2. If $M$ halts, *loop*; otherwise, *reject*.
2. Run $E$ on $\langle M_w\rangle$.
3. If $E$ accepts, *accept*; otherwise, *reject*.

If $M$ halts on $w$, then there exists some $x$ such that $M_w$ does not halt on $x$, which means $M_w$ is not a decider. Therefore $E$ does not accept $M_w$, so $N$ does not accept $\langle\langle M\rangle, w\rangle$.

If $M$ does not halt on $w$, then $M_w$ halts and reject any string $x$. Therefore $E$ accepts $M_w$, so $N$ accepts $\langle\langle M\rangle, w\rangle$.

Now the proof is complete.

---

In addition, your argument about $A_{decider}$ is wrong, because the TM in input may not be a decider and you should reject (not loop) on such case. In fact, you can prove $A_{decider}$ is also unrecognizable using similar technique.

Comment: This isn't the same language, it's somewhat like a promise problem in that I guarantee that the input TM will be a decider.

Comment: @Ryan My answer perfectly matches the question in OP. If you wrongly described the question, you can ask a new question.